# ConnectivityManager getNetworkInfo(int) deprecated

Tags: android, networking, deprecated, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-connectivitymanager

Using *compileSdkVersion 23*, however trying to support as far back as 9.

[`getNetworkInfo(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkInfo(int)) was deprecated in 23. The suggestion was to use [`getAllNetworks()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getAllNetworks()) and [`getNetworkInfo(Network)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network)) instead. However both of these require minimum of API 21.

Is there a class that we can use in the support package that can assist with this?

I know that a solution was proposed [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242384/getallnetworkinfo-is-deprecated-how-to-use-getallnetworks-to-check-network), however the challenge of my minimum API requirements of 9 poses a problem.

Comment: you can check the build version at runtime and use the appropriate method

Comment: Will this still throw a deprecated warning?

Comment: Please checkout my [ConnectivityObserver class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57215824/356895) which encapsulates API methods below and above Android Nougat.

Comment: getNetworkInfo(Network) was deprecated in API level 29

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532406/activenetworkinfo-type-is-deprecated-in-api-level-28/65251284#65251284

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You can use:

> getActiveNetworkInfo();

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (activeNetwork != null) { 
    // connected to the internet
    if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
        // connected to wifi
    } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        // connected to mobile data
    }
} else {
    // not connected to the internet
}
```

Or in a switch case

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (activeNetwork != null) { 
    // connected to the internet
    switch (activeNetwork.getType()) {
        case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
            // connected to wifi
            break;
        case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE:
            // connected to mobile data
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} else {
    // not connected to the internet
}
```

Comment: plz explain what do you mean by "in a BroadcastReceiver" - doesn't it work any other place?

Comment: @ShirishHerwade - Yes the Broadcast Receiver is not necessary in this case. getActiveNetworkInfo() can be placed in its own method provided a context reference is included.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the docs say you should always call activeNetwork.isConnected() before making network requests https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()

Comment: @TheIT - Yes doc says "You should always check isConnected() before initiating network traffic". This solution is not initiating traffic and only provided a solution to the deprecated getNetworkInfo() call.

Comment: As of Android 9, SDK 28 this is now deprecated.

Comment: This only works for current active network, what if I want to check if a specific network type is available, i.e. `getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isAvailable`?

Comment: @m0skit0 - Have you tried "boolean wifiNetwork = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isAvailable();"?

Comment: @CheeseBread That's the same code that I posted. The whole point of this question is that `getNetworkInfo` is deprecated :)

Comment: `activeNetwork.getType()` is deprecated and `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI` deprecated

Comment: Replacement is now `cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork).hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)`

Comment: @Godwin You may refer to this for more details: http://www.btechonline.org/2018/09/kotlin-determine-and-monitor.html

Comment: Am tired of this constant deprecation cycle

Answer (score 114):

**February 2020 Update:**

The accepted answer is deprecated again in `28 (Android P)`, but its replacement method only works on `23 (Android M)`. To support older devices, I wrote a helper function in both Kotlin and Java.

**How to use:**

```
int type = getConnectionType(getApplicationContext());
```

It returns an `int`, you can change it to `enum` in your code:

> 0: No Internet available (maybe on airplane mode, or in the process of joining an wi-fi).
>
> 1: Cellular (mobile data, 3G/4G/LTE whatever).
>
> 2: Wi-fi.
>
> 3: VPN

You can copy either the Kotlin or the Java version of the helper function.

**Kotlin:**

```
@IntRange(from = 0, to = 3)
fun getConnectionType(context: Context): Int {
    var result = 0 // Returns connection type. 0: none; 1: mobile data; 2: wifi; 3: vpn
    val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        cm?.run {
            cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)?.run {
                if (hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    result = 2
                } else if (hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    result = 1
                } else if (hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)){
                    result = 3
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        cm?.run {
            cm.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    result = 2
                } else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    result = 1
                } else if(type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN) {
                    result = 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

**Java:**

```
@IntRange(from = 0, to = 3)
public static int getConnectionType(Context context) {
    int result = 0; // Returns connection type. 0: none; 1: mobile data; 2: wifi; 3: vpn
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    result = 2;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    result = 1;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)) {
                    result = 3;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null) {
                // connected to the internet
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    result = 2;
                } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    result = 1;
                } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN) {
                    result = 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: As you have 2 results possible, it's better to use a boolean instead of returning an integer...

Comment: @Christian As explained in the yellow section, this helper function returns 3 possible states: `No Internet`, `Cellular` and `Wi-Fi`. If you don't care about connection type, feel free to modify the code to fit your application.

Comment: If we're strict about it, don't we require 3 branches of that if statement? Between API 21 and API 23 we can use the things that are not available in 21 yet but also not deprecated in 28

Comment: For those who do not know where the **type** variable comes from in Kotlin: `val networkInfo: NetworkInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo; networkInfo.type`

Comment: @CORONELBraian The word `type` is not a variable. It's a property of `cm.activeNetworkInfo` from the Platform. When calling `cm.activeNetworkInfo?.run` in Kotlin, the object is passed into the bracket as `this`.

Comment: what about the comment in the above solution "if you are connected to Wi-Fi and to a VPN, then your current state could be TRANSPORT_VPN, so you might want to also check for it."?

Comment: if there's only 3 states, it could be modeled with Boolean? (null=NoInternet, true=Cellular, false=Wi-Fi)

Comment: @Lukas you have to been careful if you use `Boolean` wrapper class instead of `boolean` which is primitive. In if statement you will have to add check for `null`. Also what if tomorrow another new Transport mode in NetworkCapabilities is introduced...so using integer for branching will help and also you can go for switch cases.

Comment: am tired of this constant deprecation cycle

Comment: what about TRANSPORT_ETHERNET

Comment: Why all these methods do not care about router internet connection? they just monitor data or Wi-Fi icon status. if we disconnect the router from internet, this method will show internet is connected!!!

Answer (score 73):

**As for October 2018, accepted answer is deprecated.**

`getType()`, and types themselves, are now deprecated in API Level 28. From Javadoc:

> Callers should switch to checking NetworkCapabilities#hasTransport instead with one of the NetworkCapabilities#TRANSPORT* constants

In order to use `NetworkCapabilities`, you need to pass a `Network` instance to the `getNetworkCapabilities()` method. To get that instance you need to call `getActiveNetwork()` which was added in API Level 23.

So I believe for now the right way to safely check whether you are connected to Wi-Fi or cellular network is:

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (cm != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            final NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (ni != null) {
                return (ni.isConnected() && (ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE));
            }
        } else {
            final Network n = cm.getActiveNetwork();

            if (n != null) {
                final NetworkCapabilities nc = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(n);

                return (nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI));
            }
        } 
    }

    return false; 
}
```

You can also check for other types of `TRANSPORT`, which you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.html#TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH).

**Important note:** if you are connected to Wi-Fi **and** to a VPN, then your current state could be `TRANSPORT_VPN`, so you might want to also check for it.

Don't forget to add the following permission to your AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Does hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) is equivalent to ni.isConnected() && (ni.getType() == ConnnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) ?
I mean is hasTransport() function also check if the device is connected or trying to connect ?

Comment: Once again, `NetworkInfo` is depreciated, you can no longer use `NetWorkInfo`, so how does this provide an alternative?

Comment: @PrescottChartier this code snippet only accesses NetworkInfo on SDK <23 devices

Answer (score 18):

**Updated answer (19:07:2018):**

This method will help you check if the internet connection is available.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Old answer:**

For best code reuse practice, improvising Cheese Bread answer.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    int[] networkTypes = {ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,
            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI};
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (int networkType : networkTypes) {
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetworkInfo != null &&
                    activeNetworkInfo.getType() == networkType)
                return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code can be placed in Util class and can be used to check whether the phone is connected to Internet via Wifi or Mobile Internet from any part of your application.

Comment: I'd suggest to move getting of active network outside of the for loop.

Comment: `activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()` is now deprecated

Comment: I change activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting() to activeNetwork.isConnected

Comment: NetworkInfo is now deprecated.  Need to update yet again!

Answer (score 17):

> There is an update to this answer as of March 2020 that supports API.15 through API.29, you can find it following to the original answer

**Answer February 2019**

To check if you're online:

```
boolean isOnline() {
    // Checking internet connectivity
    ConnectivityManager connectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
    if (connectivityMgr != null) {
        activeNetwork = connectivityMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }
    return activeNetwork != null;
}
```

**Kotlin:**

```
fun isOnline(): Boolean {
    val connectivityMgr = getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        return connectivityMgr.activeNetworkInfo != null

    } else {

        for (network in connectivityMgr.allNetworks) { // added in API 21 (Lollipop)
            val networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities? =
                connectivityMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
            return (networkCapabilities!!.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) &&
                    networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED) &&
                    (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                            || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                            || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)))
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

To get the type of internet connectivity before/after android M

```
void internetType() {
    // Checking internet connectivity
    ConnectivityManager connectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
    if (connectivityMgr != null) {
        activeNetwork = connectivityMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            NetworkCapabilities nc = connectivityMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityMgr.getActiveNetwork());
            if (nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                // connected to mobile data
            } else if (nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                // connected to wifi
            }
        } else {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                // connected to wifi
            } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                // connected to mobile data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All cases requires a permission to access network state

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

> **Update December 2020**

As [`NetworkInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo?hl=en) is deprecated and as of API 29 from now we have to use [`ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) with its network state change [`onAvailable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#onAvailable(android.net.Network)) & [`onLost()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#onLost(android.net.Network)) callbacks.

**Usage:**

- You can either use [this library](https://github.com/M7mdZain/InternetConnectivityLibrary), or directly use the below
  utility class which is a part of this library.

**Features**

- It's LifeCycle conscious by implementing [`LifecycleObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver) to avoid memory leakage by doing some cleanup in `onDestroy()` method.
- It supports from API 15 (Ice Cream Sandwich) through API 29 (Android Q)
- For APIs prior to API 21, it uses a context-based `BoradcastReceiver` and [`NetworkInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo), and uses [`ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) for API 21 and above.
- When both WiFi and cellular networks are on, then the connectivity listener won't interrupt when the WiFi is disconnected while transitioning to the cellular network.
- When the cellular network is on, then the connectivity listener won't interrupt when the WiFi is connected and being the active network (as this is the preferred network).
- If you're going to use the library, then no need to include this permission `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`; but you have to include it if you're going to use the utility class.

**Capabilities**

- Get the current connectivity status (online / offline).
- Continuous checking/listening to the internet connection and
  triggering a callback when the device goes offline or online.
- Get the type of the active internet connection (WiFi or Cellular).
- Get the type of all available networks (WiFi or Cellular). >> Only
  supported on API 21+
- Get the number of all available networks >> Only supported on API 21+

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
public class ConnectionUtil implements LifecycleObserver {

    private static final String TAG = "LOG_TAG";
    private ConnectivityManager mConnectivityMgr;
    private Context mContext;
    private NetworkStateReceiver mNetworkStateReceiver;
    
    /*
     * boolean indicates if my device is connected to the internet or not
     * */
    private boolean mIsConnected = false;
    private ConnectionMonitor mConnectionMonitor;


    /**
     * Indicates there is no available network.
     */
    private static final int NO_NETWORK_AVAILABLE = -1;


    /**
     * Indicates this network uses a Cellular transport.
     */
    public static final int TRANSPORT_CELLULAR = 0;


    /**
     * Indicates this network uses a Wi-Fi transport.
     */
    public static final int TRANSPORT_WIFI = 1;


    public interface ConnectionStateListener {
        void onAvailable(boolean isAvailable);
    }


    public ConnectionUtil(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mConnectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getLifecycle().addObserver(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mConnectionMonitor = new ConnectionMonitor();
            NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                    .build();
            mConnectivityMgr.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, mConnectionMonitor);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Returns true if connected to the internet, and false otherwise
     *
     * <p>
     * NetworkInfo is deprecated in API 29
     * https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo
     * <p>
     * getActiveNetworkInfo() is deprecated in API 29
     * https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo()
     * <p>
     * getNetworkInfo(int) is deprecated as of API 23
     * https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkInfo(int)
     */
    public boolean isOnline() {

        mIsConnected = false;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            // Checking internet connectivity
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
            if (mConnectivityMgr != null) {
                activeNetwork = mConnectivityMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo(); // Deprecated in API 29
            }
            mIsConnected = activeNetwork != null;

        } else {
            Network[] allNetworks = mConnectivityMgr.getAllNetworks(); // added in API 21 (Lollipop)

            for (Network network : allNetworks) {
                NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = mConnectivityMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
                if (networkCapabilities != null) {
                    if (networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) &&
                            networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED))
                        if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                                || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                                || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET))
                            mIsConnected = true;
                }
            }

        }

        return mIsConnected;

    }


    /**
     * Returns
     * <p> <p>
     * <p><p> NO_NETWORK_AVAILABLE >>> when you're offline
     * <p><p> TRANSPORT_CELLULAR >> When Cellular is the active network
     * <p><p> TRANSPORT_WIFI >> When Wi-Fi is the Active network
     * <p>
     */
    public int getActiveNetwork() {

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = mConnectivityMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo(); // Deprecated in API 29
        if (activeNetwork != null)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                NetworkCapabilities capabilities = mConnectivityMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(mConnectivityMgr.getActiveNetwork());
                if (capabilities != null)
                    if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                        // connected to mobile data
                        return TRANSPORT_CELLULAR;

                    } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                        // connected to wifi
                        return TRANSPORT_WIFI;
                    }

            } else {
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) { // Deprecated in API 28
                    // connected to mobile data
                    return TRANSPORT_CELLULAR;

                } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) { // Deprecated in API 28
                    // connected to wifi
                    return TRANSPORT_WIFI;
                }
            }
        return NO_NETWORK_AVAILABLE;
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public int getAvailableNetworksCount() {

        int count = 0;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Network[] allNetworks = mConnectivityMgr.getAllNetworks(); // added in API 21 (Lollipop)
            for (Network network : allNetworks) {
                NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = mConnectivityMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
                if (networkCapabilities != null)
                    if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                            || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR))
                        count++;
            }

        }

        return count;
    }
    

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public List<Integer> getAvailableNetworks() {

        List<Integer> activeNetworks = new ArrayList<>();

        Network[] allNetworks; // added in API 21 (Lollipop)
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            allNetworks = mConnectivityMgr.getAllNetworks();
            for (Network network : allNetworks) {
                NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = mConnectivityMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
                if (networkCapabilities != null) {
                    if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI))
                        activeNetworks.add(TRANSPORT_WIFI);

                    if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR))
                        activeNetworks.add(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);

                }
            }
        }

        return activeNetworks;
    }


    public void onInternetStateListener(ConnectionStateListener listener) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mNetworkStateReceiver = new NetworkStateReceiver(listener);
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            mContext.registerReceiver(mNetworkStateReceiver, intentFilter);

        } else {
            mConnectionMonitor.setOnConnectionStateListener(listener);
        }
    }


    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (mConnectionMonitor != null)
                mConnectivityMgr.unregisterNetworkCallback(mConnectionMonitor);
        } else {
            if (mNetworkStateReceiver != null)
                mContext.unregisterReceiver(mNetworkStateReceiver);
        }

    }


    public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        ConnectionStateListener mListener;

        public NetworkStateReceiver(ConnectionStateListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

                NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = mConnectivityMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo(); // deprecated in API 29

                /*
                 * activeNetworkInfo.getState() deprecated in API 28
                 * NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED deprecated in API 29
                 * */
                if (!mIsConnected && activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + "Connected To: " + activeNetworkInfo.getTypeName());
                    mIsConnected = true;
                    mListener.onAvailable(true);

                } else if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
                    if (!isOnline()) {
                        mListener.onAvailable(false);
                        mIsConnected = false;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public class ConnectionMonitor extends ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {

        private ConnectionStateListener mConnectionStateListener;

        void setOnConnectionStateListener(ConnectionStateListener connectionStateListener) {
            mConnectionStateListener = connectionStateListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {

            if (mIsConnected)
                return;

            Log.d(TAG, "onAvailable: ");

            if (mConnectionStateListener != null) {
                mConnectionStateListener.onAvailable(true);
                mIsConnected = true;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(@NonNull Network network) {

            if (getAvailableNetworksCount() == 0) {
                if (mConnectionStateListener != null)
                    mConnectionStateListener.onAvailable(false);
                mIsConnected = false;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

### **Kotlin version**

```
class ConnectionUtil(var mContext: Context) : LifecycleObserver {

    private val TAG = "LOG_TAG"

    companion object NetworkType {

        /**
         * Indicates this network uses a Cellular transport.
         */
        const val TRANSPORT_CELLULAR = 0

        /**
         * Indicates this network uses a Wi-Fi transport.
         */
       const val TRANSPORT_WIFI = 1

    }

    private var mConnectivityMgr: ConnectivityManager? = null

    //    private var mContext: Context? = null
    private var mNetworkStateReceiver: NetworkStateReceiver? = null

    /*
     * boolean indicates if my device is connected to the internet or not
     * */
    private var mIsConnected = false
    private var mConnectionMonitor: ConnectionMonitor? = null


    /**
     * Indicates there is no available network.
     */
    private val NO_NETWORK_AVAILABLE = -1


    interface ConnectionStateListener {
        fun onAvailable(isAvailable: Boolean)
    }

    init {
        mConnectivityMgr =
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        (mContext as AppCompatActivity?)!!.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mConnectionMonitor = ConnectionMonitor()
            val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                .build()
            mConnectivityMgr!!.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, mConnectionMonitor!!)
        }
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if connected to the internet, and false otherwise
     *
     * NetworkInfo is deprecated in API 29
     * https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo
     *
     * getActiveNetworkInfo() is deprecated in API 29
     * https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo()
     *
     * getNetworkInfo(int) is deprecated as of API 23
     * https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkInfo(int)
     */
    fun isOnline(): Boolean {
        mIsConnected = false
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            // Checking internet connectivity
            var activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = null
            if (mConnectivityMgr != null) {
                activeNetwork = mConnectivityMgr!!.activeNetworkInfo // Deprecated in API 29
            }
            mIsConnected = activeNetwork != null
        } else {
            val allNetworks = mConnectivityMgr!!.allNetworks // added in API 21 (Lollipop)
            for (network in allNetworks) {
                val networkCapabilities = mConnectivityMgr!!.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
                if (networkCapabilities != null) {
                    if (networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) &&
                        networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)
                    ) 
                        if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                            || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                            || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)
                        ) mIsConnected = true
                }
            }
        }
        return mIsConnected
    }


    /**
     * Returns:
     *
     * NO_NETWORK_AVAILABLE >>> when you're offline
     * TRANSPORT_CELLULAR >> When Cellular is the active network
     * TRANSPORT_WIFI >> When Wi-Fi is the Active network
     */
    fun getActiveNetwork(): Int {
        val activeNetwork = mConnectivityMgr!!.activeNetworkInfo // Deprecated in API 29
        if (activeNetwork != null) if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val capabilities = mConnectivityMgr!!.getNetworkCapabilities(
                mConnectivityMgr!!.activeNetwork
            )
            if (capabilities != null) if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                // connected to mobile data
                return TRANSPORT_CELLULAR
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                // connected to wifi
                return TRANSPORT_WIFI
            }
        } else {
            if (activeNetwork.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) { // Deprecated in API 28
                // connected to mobile data
                return TRANSPORT_CELLULAR
            } else if (activeNetwork.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) { // Deprecated in API 28
                // connected to wifi
                return TRANSPORT_WIFI
            }
        }
        return NO_NETWORK_AVAILABLE
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    fun getAvailableNetworksCount(): Int {
        var count = 0
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val allNetworks = mConnectivityMgr!!.allNetworks // added in API 21 (Lollipop)
            for (network in allNetworks) {
                val networkCapabilities = mConnectivityMgr!!.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
                if (networkCapabilities != null) if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(
                        NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI
                    )
                    || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                ) count++
            }
        }
        return count
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    fun getAvailableNetworks(): List<Int> {
        val activeNetworks: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
        val allNetworks: Array<Network> // added in API 21 (Lollipop)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            allNetworks = mConnectivityMgr!!.allNetworks
            for (network in allNetworks) {
                val networkCapabilities = mConnectivityMgr!!.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
                if (networkCapabilities != null) {
                    if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) activeNetworks.add(
                        TRANSPORT_WIFI
                    )
                    if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) activeNetworks.add(
                        TRANSPORT_CELLULAR
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        return activeNetworks
    }


    fun onInternetStateListener(listener: ConnectionStateListener) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mNetworkStateReceiver = NetworkStateReceiver(listener)
            val intentFilter = IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
            mContext.registerReceiver(mNetworkStateReceiver, intentFilter)
        } else {
            mConnectionMonitor!!.setOnConnectionStateListener(listener)
        }
    }


    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy")
        (mContext as AppCompatActivity?)!!.lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (mConnectionMonitor != null) mConnectivityMgr!!.unregisterNetworkCallback(
                mConnectionMonitor!!
            )
        } else {
            if (mNetworkStateReceiver != null) mContext.unregisterReceiver(mNetworkStateReceiver)
        }
    }


    inner class NetworkStateReceiver(var mListener: ConnectionStateListener) :
        BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.extras != null) {
                val activeNetworkInfo: NetworkInfo? =
                    mConnectivityMgr?.getActiveNetworkInfo() // deprecated in API 29

                /*
                 * activeNetworkInfo.getState() deprecated in API 28
                 * NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED deprecated in API 29
                 * */if (!mIsConnected && activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    mIsConnected = true
                    mListener.onAvailable(true)
                } else if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                        ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,
                        java.lang.Boolean.FALSE
                    )
                ) {
                    if (!isOnline()) {
                        mListener.onAvailable(false)
                        mIsConnected = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    inner class ConnectionMonitor : NetworkCallback() {
        private var mConnectionStateListener: ConnectionStateListener? = null
        fun setOnConnectionStateListener(connectionStateListener: ConnectionStateListener?) {
            mConnectionStateListener = connectionStateListener
        }

        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            if (mIsConnected) return
            Log.d(TAG, "onAvailable: ")
            if (mConnectionStateListener != null) {
                mConnectionStateListener!!.onAvailable(true)
                mIsConnected = true
            }
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            if (getAvailableNetworksCount() == 0) {
                mConnectionStateListener?.onAvailable(false)
                mIsConnected = false
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Rasel please check updated answer, hope it could help

Comment: If user is connected to Wifi and mobile data at the same time, and loses connection in one of them `onLost` will get called. `onLost` doesn't mean device lost the internet connection, but a Network lost the connection.

Comment: @Gokhan Arik.. Nice catch I am working on it solving it

Comment: Check this discussion https://gist.github.com/PasanBhanu/730a32a9eeb180ec2950c172d54bb06a

Comment: @GokhanArik thanks for help.. I just updated my answer and expanded API usage, plz let me know if you notice any bugs

Comment: Still doesn't solve `onLost` issue. Check the gist I sent, and see my last comment there. You need to keep track of a list of Networks and use the Network argument from the call. Checking `isOnline` inside async call is not advised. Read the header of `NetworkInfo` class `@deprecated` section

Comment: @GokhanArik thanks again, `onLost()` is now OK, no more handlers/async code; solved it by tracking the no. of connected networks with `getAvailableNetworksCount()`

Comment: `API.15 through API.29` - Does this mean it doesn't work on API.30 and later or just that it couldn't be guaranteed when the answer was last edited given the frequency of previous deprecations? If so can it be updated?

Comment: @hippietrail It's 3 years now; let me check it out.. thanks for the notification

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is deprecated in version 28 so here is the solution that I am using in my project.

> Returns connection type. false: no Internet Connection; true: mobile
>   data || wifi

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) { 
    boolean result = false; 
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    result = true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null) {
                // connected to the internet
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    result = true;
                } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: activeNetwork.getType() is deprecated also. You can use activeNetwork.isConnected();

Answer (score 7):

Many answers still use **getNetworkType** below 23 which is deprecated; use below code to check if the device has an internet connection.

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (cm != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());
            return capabilities != null && (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) || capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR));
        } else {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

..

And, do not forget to add this line in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 7):

This can help someone
**Kotlin**

```
fun isNetworkConnected(context: Context) : Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val capabilities =  connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        capabilities.also {
            if (it != null){
                if (it.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI))
                    return true
                else if (it.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)){
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Perfect this code and return true value of internet should get either wifi or data pack. Thanks !!

Comment: available from api 23+

Answer (score 5):

It is good to check whether your network is connected to Internet:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    try {
        val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
            val an = cm.activeNetwork ?: return false
            val capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(an) ?: return false
            capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        } else {
            val a = cm.activeNetworkInfo ?: return false
            a.isConnected && (a.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || a.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: You might also want to check [`NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.html#NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED).

Answer (score 3):

As [Cheese Bread suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771164/356895), use 
          [getActiveNetworkInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo())

> getActiveNetworkInfo
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> NetworkInfo getActiveNetworkInfo ()
>
> Returns details about the currently active default data network. When connected, this network is the default route for outgoing connections. You should always check isConnected() before initiating network traffic. This may return null when there is no default network.
>   This method requires the caller to hold the permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
>   Returns
>   NetworkInfo
>   a NetworkInfo object for the current default network or null if no default network is currently active.
>
> Reference : Android Studio

```
 public final boolean isInternetOn() {

    // get Connectivity Manager object to check connection
    ConnectivityManager connec =
            (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(getBaseContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Check for network connections
    if ( connec.getActiveNetworkInfo().getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connec.getActiveNetworkInfo().getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ) {

        // if connected with internet

        Toast.makeText(this, connec.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;

    } else if (
            connec.getActiveNetworkInfo().getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||
                    connec.getActiveNetworkInfo().getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  ) {

        Toast.makeText(this, " Not Connected ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

now call the method , for safe use try catch

```
try {
    if (isInternetOn()) { /* connected actions */ }
    else { /* not connected actions */ }
} catch (Exception e){
  Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And do not forget to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: thank you it's useful. when we check network status and if wifi and data both are off- that time app crash but try catch solve the issue..

Comment: However this does not work if I want to check if a specific type of network is present enumerate all networks present, i.e. `getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET).isAvailable`

Comment: getState() deprecated!

Comment: Several deprecated instructions!

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin version:

```
fun isInternetOn(context: Context): Boolean {
   val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ConnectivityManager
   val activeNetwork = cm?.activeNetworkInfo
   return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if Internet is available:

```
@RequiresPermission(allOf = [
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
    Manifest.permission.INTERNET
])
fun isInternetAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
    val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager!!.activeNetworkInfo
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected
}
```

Answer (score 3):

connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork() is not found in below android M (API 28).
networkInfo.getState() is deprecated above android L.

So, final answer is:

```
public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context mContext) {
    if (mContext == null) return false;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            final Network network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
            if (network != null) {
                final NetworkCapabilities nc = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);

                return (nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) ||
                        nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI));
            }
        } else {
            NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo tempNetworkInfo : networkInfos) {
                if (tempNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You say getActiveNetwork() is not found in Android below M, but your code uses it on Lollipop !?

Answer (score 2):

In order to be on the safe side, i would suggest to use also method

> NetworkInfo.isConnected()

#### The whole method could be as below:

```
/**
 * Checking whether network is connected
 * @param context Context to get {@link ConnectivityManager}
 * @return true if Network is connected, else false
 */
public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        int networkType = activeNetwork.getType();
        return networkType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || networkType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `activeNetwork.getType()` is deprecated and `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI ` deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I check if the current network is using cellular or not on the latest Android versions:

```
val isCellular: Boolean get() {
    val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork).hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
    } else {
        cm.activeNetworkInfo?.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(Almost) All answers are deprecated in Android P.

`Java`:

```
public boolean IsOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (cm == null) return false;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (ni == null) return false;

        return ni.isConnected() && (ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }

    NetworkCapabilities nc = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());

    if (nc == null) return false;

    return nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) || nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
}
```

`C#`:

```
public bool IsOnline(Context context)
{
    var cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
   
    if (cm == null) return false;

    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.M)
    {
        var ni = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo;

        if (ni == null) return false;

        return ni.IsConnected && (ni.Type == ConnectivityType.Wifi || ni.Type == ConnectivityType.Mobile);
    }

    return cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork).HasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Wifi)
        || cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork).HasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Cellular);
}
```

The key here is `NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_XXX` (`Android.Net.TransportType`)

Answer (score 2):

We may need to check internet connectivity more than once. So it will be easier for us if we write the code block in an extension method of `Context`. Below are my helper extensions for `Context` and `Fragment`.

**Checking Internet Connection**

```
fun Context.hasInternet(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected
    } else {
        val nc = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (nc == null) {
            false
        } else {
            nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) ||
                    nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        }
    }
}
```

**Other Extensions**

```
fun Context.hasInternet(notifyNoInternet: Boolean = true, trueFunc: (internet: Boolean) -> Unit) {
    if (hasInternet()) {
        trueFunc(true)
    } else if (notifyNoInternet) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

fun Context.hasInternet(
    trueFunc: (internet: Boolean) -> Unit,
    falseFunc: (internet: Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    if (hasInternet()) {
        trueFunc(true)
    } else {
        falseFunc(true)
    }
}

fun Fragment.hasInternet(): Boolean = context!!.hasInternet()

fun Fragment.hasInternet(notifyNoInternet: Boolean = true, trueFunc: (internet: Boolean) -> Unit) =
    context!!.hasInternet(notifyNoInternet, trueFunc)

fun Fragment.hasInternet(
    trueFunc: (internet: Boolean) -> Unit, falseFunc: (internet: Boolean) -> Unit
) = context!!.hasInternet(trueFunc, falseFunc)
```

Answer (score 2):

**The below code works on all APIs.(Kotlin)**

**However, getActiveNetworkInfo() is deprecated only in API 29 and works on all APIs , so we can use it in all Api's below 29**

```
fun isInternetAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
            var result = false
            val connectivityManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
                val actNw =
                    connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(networkCapabilities) ?: return false
                result = when {
                    actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                    actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                    actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                    else -> false
                }
            } else {
                connectivityManager.run {
                    connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                        result = when (type) {
                            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI -> true
                            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE -> true
                            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET -> true
                            else -> false
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            return result
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.agnosticdev.com/content/how-detect-network-connectivity-android

please follow this tutorial it should help anyone looking for answers.

note networkInfo has been deprecated hence replace it is isNetworkReacheable()
with @vidha answer below
passing getApplicationContext() as parameter

```
  public static boolean isNetworkReacheable(Context context) {
    boolean result = false;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    result = true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null) {
                // connected to the internet
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    result = true;
                } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work in Android 10 as well. It will return true if connected to the internet else return false.

```
private fun isOnline(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val capabilities =
                connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            when {
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR")
                    return true
                }
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI")
                    return true
                }
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> {
                    Log.i("Internet", "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET")
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: available from api 23+

Answer (score 1):

Since answers posted only allow you to query the active network, here's how to get `NetworkInfo` for any network, not only the active one (for example Wifi network) (sorry, Kotlin code ahead)

```
(getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager).run {
    allNetworks.find { getNetworkInfo(it).type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI }?.let { network -> getNetworkInfo(network) }
//    getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isAvailable // This is the deprecated API pre-21
}
```

This requires API 21 or higher and the permission `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`

Comment: currentNetwork.getType() and ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI are both deprecated in API 28.

Comment: @Abushawish What is the recommended solution for API 28?

Comment: Replacement is now `cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork).hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)`

Answer (score 1):

**NetManager** that you can use to check internet connection on Android with **Kotlin**

If you use **minSdkVersion >= 23**

```
class NetManager @Inject constructor(var applicationContext: Context) {
    val isConnectedToInternet: Boolean?
        get() = with(
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
                    as ConnectivityManager
        ) {
            isConnectedToInternet()
        }
}

fun ConnectivityManager.isConnectedToInternet() = isConnected(getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork))

fun isConnected(networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities?): Boolean {
    return when (networkCapabilities) {
        null -> false
        else -> with(networkCapabilities) { hasTransport(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || hasTransport(TRANSPORT_WIFI) }
    }
}
```

If you use **minSdkVersion < 23**

```
class NetManager @Inject constructor(var applicationContext: Context) {
    val isConnectedToInternet: Boolean?
        get() = with(
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
                    as ConnectivityManager
        ) {
            isConnectedToInternet()
        }
}

fun ConnectivityManager.isConnectedToInternet(): Boolean = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
    isConnected(activeNetworkInfo)
} else {
    isConnected(getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork))
}


fun isConnected(network: NetworkInfo?): Boolean {
    return when (network) {
        null -> false
        else -> with(network) { isConnected && (type == TYPE_WIFI || type == TYPE_MOBILE) }
    }
}

fun isConnected(networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities?): Boolean {
    return when (networkCapabilities) {
        null -> false
        else -> with(networkCapabilities) { hasTransport(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || hasTransport(TRANSPORT_WIFI) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public boolean hasConnection(final Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNW = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNW != null && activeNW.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in the main program body:

```
if(hasConnection(this)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Active networks OK ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getAccountData(token, tel);
}
else  Toast.makeText(this, "No active networks... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Android M (api 23), some properties (e.g. `getActiveNetworkInfo()`) are deprecated.

Combining the knowledge from some answers in here, with latest guidance and APIs, into a very useful extension function in Kotlin. In a separate file, you can write the following:

```
fun Context.hasNetwork(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkConnected(connectivityManager)
    } else {
        checkConnectedLegacy(connectivityManager)
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
fun checkConnected(connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager): Boolean {
    val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
    activeNetwork ?: return false
    val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork)
    capabilities ?: return false
    return capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
}

fun checkConnectedLegacy(connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager): Boolean {
    val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    networkInfo ?: return false
    return networkInfo.isConnected && (networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
}
```

This will then allow you to write the follow from any place where you can access context, e.g. for a Fragment:

```
 if (requireContext().hasNetwork()) {
  // do whatever if you HAVE network
} else {
  // handle no network state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isConnectedToWifi(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Network network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
        if (capabilities == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    } else {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (networkInfo == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Kotlin. Lot of API's are deprecated in Network Manager class so below answer cover all API support.

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    var result = false
    (context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager).apply {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                result = isCapableNetwork(this,this.activeNetwork)
            } else {
                val networkInfos = this.allNetworks
                for (tempNetworkInfo in networkInfos) {
                    if(isCapableNetwork(this,tempNetworkInfo))
                        result =  true
                }
            }
        }

    return result
}

fun isCapableNetwork(cm: ConnectivityManager,network: Network?): Boolean{
     cm.getNetworkCapabilities(network)?.also {
        if (it.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            return true
        } else if (it.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

You will also add below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking network status with ***target SDK 29*** :

```
@IntRange(from = 0, to = 3)
fun getConnectionType(context: Context): Int {
    var result = 0 // Returns connection type. 0: none; 1: mobile data; 2: wifi
    val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val capabilities =
            cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                result = 2
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                result = 1
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)) {
                result = 3
            }
        }
    } else {
        val activeNetwork = cm.activeNetworkInfo
        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            // connected to the internet
            if (activeNetwork.type === ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                result = 2
            } else if (activeNetwork.type === ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                result = 1
            } else if (activeNetwork.type === ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN) {
                result = 3
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Vin-Norman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6842292/vin-norman) answer I made a few modifications for the below Android API Level 23 and provided it in Java.

```
class Util {
  public static boolean hasNetwork(@NonNull Context context) {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                return checkConnected(connectivityManager);
            } else {
                return checkConnectedLegacy(connectivityManager);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public static boolean checkConnected(ConnectivityManager connectivityManager) {
        Network network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
        if (network == null) return false;
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
        if (capabilities == null) return false;
        return capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    }

    public static boolean checkConnectedLegacy(ConnectivityManager connectivityManager) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if(Util.hasNetwork(context){
 //your code...
}
```