# getAllNetworkInfo() is Deprecated

Tags: android, networking, connection, android-6.0-marshmallow

I wrote this code.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 

    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {}
```

But getAllNetworkInfo() is deprecated. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

as the docs say:

`getAllNetworkInfo()`

> This method was deprecated in API level 23. This method does not support multiple connected networks of the same type. Use `getAllNetworks()` and `getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network)` instead.

I think you can use `getActiveNetworkInfo()`:

Here is the code:

```
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
            MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo nInfo=connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (nInfo != null && nInfo.getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            //do your thing
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Network[] networks = connectivity.getAllNetworks();
        NetworkInfo networkInfo;
        for (Network mNetwork : networks) {
            networkInfo = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(mNetwork);
            if (networkInfo.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

        }
    }

    return false;
}}
```

You can use this class for detecting internet connection. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771164/4279451

You can use:

> getActiveNetworkInfo();

```
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                // connected to wifi
                Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
                Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            // not connected to the internet
        }
```