# How to identify if WiFi state is active using getNetworkInfo?

Tags: android

I am having some problem in my simple app. In my code I am using a deprecated code so I read this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkInfo%28int%29) and I don't know how can I get the wifi status using this function `getNetworkInfo (Network network)`
Before my code looks like this to identify its state.

```
 boolean wifi = conman.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Can you help me with this?

In using this method  `getNetworkInfo (Network network)` what parameter should I put in order to get the state of the wifi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to see if wifi is connected in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226129/getallnetworkinfo-is-deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
ConnectivityManager manager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isWifi = (netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
boolean isConnected = (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());
```

DONE.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static boolean isOnline(Context mContext) {
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)   mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo mWifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (mWifi != null && mWifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: how is it related to wifi?. It can be Mobile data as well.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>