# Android N not sending android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcast?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I have defined a receiver in a sandbox Android N application:

```
<receiver
    android:exported="true"
    android:name="com.sandboxapplication.NetworkReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It's rather simple:

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = NetworkReceiver.class.getName();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received Network Change event.");
    }
}
```

This receiver is working fine if in my build.gradle file my targetSdkVersion is 23. However, if I set my targetSdkVersion to 24, the receiver never receives anything. In fact if I place a debug break point in my receiver Android Studio gives me the visual indication that it looks like the class is never even loaded into memory.

Did I miss something very basic in the Android N documentation? Is there a new way to detect connectivity change events?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY\_ACTION deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421930/connectivitymanager-connectivity-action-deprecated)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apps targeting Android `N (Nougat)` do not receive `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcasts, even if they have manifest entries to request notification of these events. Apps that are running can still listen for `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` on their main thread if they request notification with a `BroadcastReceiver`.

To see what changed in `Android N (Nougat)`. Please refer below link.
[Android N Behaviour Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew I must have missed something very basic in the documentation...

Comment: @DanMD That's probably because https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION doesn't make the slightest effort to mention this... What a waste of time.

Comment: Working link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html

Comment: Thanks for updating the link.

Comment: Is there a work around? What is the syntax to get the connectivity change via "registering BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver()"

Comment: @FrankZappa: Use this code to register receiver in your Activity or in Application class - 

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
IntentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(new NetworkConnectionReceiver(), intentFilter);

Note: If register this receiver in Activity, don't forget to unregister it.

Comment: Monitor for changes in connectivity
Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they declare the broadcast receiver in their manifest. Apps will still receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid. https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring

Answer (score 26):

Use this code to register receiver in your `Activity` or in `Application` class

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(); 
intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTI‌​ON); 
registerReceiver(new NetworkConnectionReceiver(), intentFilter);
```

Where **`NetworkConnectionReceiver`** is a class extended by `BroadcastReceiver`. Just add this class in your app and perform action in `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method.

**Note:** If you register this receiver in an `Activity`, don't forget to unregister it.

Comment: In Nougat, Will the BroadcastReceiver triggers when the app is force closed ?

Comment: @Priya No, when the app is force closed the process is gone and everything registered in code is gone too. You should only listen to this broadcast when the app is in the foreground anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTI‌​ON` was deprecated:

```
@deprecated 
apps should use the more versatile {@link #requestNetwork},
{@link #registerNetworkCallback} or {@link #registerDefaultNetworkCallback}
functions instead for faster and more detailed updates about the network
changes they care about.
```

So `registerDefaultNetworkCallback` should be used:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
cm.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
        doOnNetworkConnected();
    }
});
```

Comment: On adding this code it's saying "Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21)". What to write for lower api levels devices ?

Comment: @AmbarJain just use deprecated method. It will not be removed from old devices.

Comment: but this will only work if the app is run/running right? if the app is not running, there is no way.

Comment: ouch. tough luck. looks like there is no way to detect online/offline anymore. Sure, JobScheduler has constraints but only for CONNECTED network type. WorkManager's minimum periodic re-run is 15minutes (too long).