# BroadCast onReceiver() not calling on Marshmallow and above SDK's

Tags: android, service, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to start services from Broadcast Receiver but Marshmallow and above SDK's will not callback. **BOOT_COMPLETED** is working fine with app foreground & background but **CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE** is not working on background .

My requirement is, i want to get callback when app with app foreground & background.

**My manifest** :

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.MessageBroadCastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My **Broadcast Receiver**:

```
public class MessageBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "MessageBroadCastReceive";
private Context ctx;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "AppBroad " + intent.getAction());
    this.ctx = context;
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            RestartMessageService();

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")) {
            RestartMessageService();

    }
}
}
```

am tired to registered the Broadcast actions in my main activity its working fine on foreground, once i close my app it will not call (Marshmallow and above SDK's).

**Registered code:**

```
    private void RegisterReceivers() {
    try {
        MessageBroadCastReceiver broadCastReceiver = new MessageBroadCastReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        getBaseContext().registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, intentFilter);
        PrefManager.getInstance(this).setBroadcastReg(true);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please give me solution.

Advance thanks...

Comment: You will need to open the app once to receive broadcast check this for more info -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226410/android-boot-completed-not-received-when-application-is-closed/19856367#19856367

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076910/android-n-not-sending-android-net-conn-connectivity-change-broadcast.

Comment: @ADM am also register `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE `action  but it works only on app foreground, my question is there any way to get call back on background.

Comment: @AravindV  i see the link its fine on user when force stop the app. But actions are still not callback when running on background.

Comment: same thing i applied in my project it's working for me any how once again i will check for you

Comment: In Which class have u implemented the code

Comment: @AravindV From launching activity.

Comment: @Mathan Chinna I am getting the trigger response when my app is in back ground condition also on oreo version . i don't think their was a issue with broad cast. 

I Think you are unregistering an event on stop method .
Try to unregister event on onDestroy method

Comment: @AravindV thanks aravind, but actually am not using unregister event at any method.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with Marshmallow and above? Because according to this [doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#bg-opt), for sure you won't be able to register for `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` for Nougat and above.

Comment: @RickSanchez yes am testing the Nougat and above devices, its working into app foreground only when i close my app i didn't get any callback.

Comment: `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` is an implicit broadcast. There is no way you will be able to register your broadcast receiver unless your app is in foreground.

Comment: @RickSanchez thanks, now `Service` class is not working and `BroadcastReceiver` also not working on `O` then how to get connectivity status on app background. Please tell me if there any way to get the connectivity status on app background.

Comment: This is a step taken by Google to reduce battery usage of the phone. I am sorry to say, there is no way to observe system events like `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE ` in the app background.

Comment: @RickSanchez it's ok rick, thanks for the response.