# Android - ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO deprecated

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I am creating a BroadcastReceiver to listen for Wi-Fi connectivity changes:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO); // deprecated

            // Get connectivity details from networkInfo...

        }

    }

}, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

However, `ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO` is deprecated, so how else to get the `NetworkInfo` object?

Comment: see this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421930/connectivitymanager-connectivity-action-deprecated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **getActiveNetworkInfo();**

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's what I'm currently doing. I just wondered if there was a way to get a `NetworkInfo` object directly from the intent supplied to my BroadcastReceiver's`onReceive(...)` method, but seemingly not.

Comment: From CONTEXT you need to fetch that via ConnectivityManager.