# JobIntentService runs periodically?

Tags: android, android-service, jobintentservice

I have a JobIntentService in my project.
 But When i make startService to this Service, "*onHandleWork*" methods runs only 1 time. how can i make it run periodically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Job Service is just a service, which does not mean to run periodically itself.

You will have to run it periodically using [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler), [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), or [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms).

See [this answer that may help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51360718/6891563)