# Service start on boot and don't killed after Activity onDestroy()

Tags: android, android-service-binding, bluetooth-gatt

I want to start a service when device is booted. I found BOOT_COMPLETED intent filter. I also want the service running all the time, if the application call `onDestroy()`, the service is always running.

**Resume of my goal:**

MainActivity <-> Service

These communicate to send message and receive message in both ways , the service is intended to initialise the Bluetooth connection (pairing if disconnected) (Bluetooth GATT), to be able to reconnect to the different devices if necessary and to receive requests from the application that will transmit to the different devices passing through this service. I use this :

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32959842437.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dXR3VJu

Thank you for your help.

Comment: well you should check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289236/continually-running-background-service

Comment: Bind is lost when i close my application?