# Get everywhere in my application the last current location android

Tags: android, google-geolocation

I have reformulated my problems on how to create a service in the background to get always and at any point of the application using shared preferences that are updated at each change of latitude and longitude.

Here are my specific questions about it:

1) Is there a way that if there is no GPS coverage it uses the internet and vice versa?

2) What are the examples and where do I find them that can work from the version of android min 5/6 and max last version?

3) Should I launch the service from the main activity or directly from the splash screen?

4) I have seen that there are problems with permissions with the android version 8.0 oreo .... I have a huawei as a test cell phone at the moment ....

At the moment no other questions come to mind. Eventually I will ask you ...
Thanks for any helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **service** to achieve this.
I will prefer Work-Manager service.

before that go through it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51360718/5328951

Comment: i need more example please.....