# Network Changed Broadcast Receiver does not execute in One Plus Phones

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReciever` name `NetworkReciver.java` that executes when Internet is Connected or Disconnected. And it is working well.

But when app is closed from recent apps, then `NetworkReciver.java` does not executes in One Plus 6 Phone while it works proper in Samsung Phones.

I am not getting why the behavior is different in One Plus Device

My Code:

**Manifest**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


  <receiver android:name=".NetworkReciever" >
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
       </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

NetworkReciever.java:

```
  public class NetworkReciever extends BroadcastReceiver 
  {

       @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
     {
            Log.i("TAG", "Network REceiver Executed");
     }
}
```

**Problem:**

NetworkReciever does not execute when app is closed from recent apps in One Plus Device.

Comment: Killing app from the recent drawer and `NetworkReciever` has no relation, your receiver will be called when your app is running and internet connection changes its state

Comment: Yes, It must work. But it is not working in One Plus 6.
I checked many times and then posted here.

Comment: What is the API version of your android device?

Comment: One Plus 6  Android 8.1 API level 27

Comment: use dynamic broadcast receiver. Android 8 does not support static broadcast receiver.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421930/connectivitymanager-connectivity-action-deprecated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY\_ACTION deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421930/connectivitymanager-connectivity-action-deprecated)

Answer (score 4):

Starting in Android N, the system does not send `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcasts to manifest receivers of applications targeting N+.

Explicit `BroadcastReceivers` registered via `Context.registerReceiver()` continue to receive these broadcasts.

Solution: See [ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421930/connectivitymanager-connectivity-action-deprecated)

Answer (score 2):

Apps targeting Android 7.0+ do not receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they register to receive them in their manifest, and processes that depend on this broadcast will not start.

So, if you want to do some work when internet connection is available. You can use [Job scheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization#sched-jobs) or [work manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/).

For example, here is sample code for job scheduler.

```
public static final int MY_BACKGROUND_JOB = 0;
...
public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
  JobScheduler js =
      (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
  JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(
    MY_BACKGROUND_JOB,
    new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class))
      .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
      .setRequiresCharging(true)
      .build();
  js.schedule(job);
}
```

When the conditions for your job are met, your app receives a callback to run the onStartJob() method in the specified JobService.class

[Android JobScheduler Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-jobscheduler)

Also, registering broadcasts in the activity's onCreate and unregistering it in onDestroy will not work for your case as you will not receive the broadcast after the app is killed.

Comment: did this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

**In Android Nougat, Android does not broadcast for network changes to manifest registered BroadcastReceiver.**

From the [Android Nogout Changes](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring#java) & Also mentioned in [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)

> #### Monitor for changes in connectivity
>
> Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive
>   [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) broadcasts if they declare the broadcast receiver
>   in their manifest. Apps will still receive [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
>   broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with
>   [Context.registerReceiver()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) and that context is still valid.

#### Solution

> NetworkReciever does not execute when app is closed from recent apps

I don't know why you want to get network changes after the app is closed. But in this case you have to make some periodic task with **[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)** or **[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)**. I suggest you use **WorkManager** because it will work for all devices. whether **JobScheduler** is available only for devices >= 21 version. [Here](https://medium.com/exploring-code/exploring-jetpack-scheduling-tasks-with-work-manager-fba20d7c69bf) is a good example for WorkManager (It is quite easy).

### Background solution (execute when only you need)

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {

        // get online status

         boolean isOnline =  isOnline(getApplicationContext());

        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return Result.SUCCESS;

        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)
    }

    public boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
    }
}
```

and schedule this Work at app start.

```
public static void scheduleWork() {

    int TIME_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 15;
    PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder photoCheckBuilder = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker .class, TIME_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    PeriodicWorkRequest photoCheckWork = photoCheckBuilder.build();
    WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance();
    if (instance != null) {
        instance.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("TAG", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, photoCheckWork);
    }
}
```

### Foreground solution (recommended)

Or if you just want to receive network changes when you app is live. You can below solution.

- Register this receiver in your `BaseActivity`. or create one if you don't have yet any BaseActivity.
- Register on `onStart()` and unregister on `onStop()`. Because you may not want to invoke your UI after `onStop()`.

Here is **`BaseActivity.java`**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by KHEMRAJ on 9/5/2018.
 */
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    NetworkReceiver receiver;
    public boolean isOnline;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        isOnline = isOnline(this);
        // register network change receiver
        receiver = new NetworkReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // unregister network change receiver
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        receiver = null;
    }

    public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            isOnline = isOnline(context);
            Log.i("TAG", "Network REceiver Executed");
        }
    }

    public boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
    }
}
```

> I suggested you WorkManger only, because I created a sample earlier
>   days with **[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)**, **[EvernoteJobs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)**,
>   **[AlarmManager](https://medium.com/exploring-code/exploring-jetpack-scheduling-tasks-with-work-manager-fba20d7c69bf)**, **[JobService][7]**, and **[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring#java)**. In which I started periodic task of 15 minutes with each of these. and
>   wrote logs of each in separate file when invoked.
>
> Conclusion of this test was that. **[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring#java)** and **[EvernoteJobs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)** were
>   most efficient to do jobs. Now because EvernoteJobs will use
>   WorkManager from next version. So I came up with WorkManager.

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause:**

From Android N OnePlus introduced a feature similar to Mi devices which prevent certain apps from auto-starting after reboot. I suspect that same feature is preventing your app to receive `BroadcastReceiver` as well.

**Solution**

Use `AccessibilityService` service in your app and ask user to turn on `AccessibilityService` for your app from Settings and boing doing this `BroadcastReceiver` in your app will work as expected.

Since `AccessibilityService` is a system level service, so by registering your own service you are passing the certain filter applied by these manufacturers and as soon as your custom `AccessibilityService` gets triggered by the `OS`, your app becomes active in receiving the eligible `BroadcastReceiver` that you had registered.

Here is how you can register your own `AccessibilityService`.

Create your custom `AccessibilityService`

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {//do nothing }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() { //do nothing}
}
```

Create configuration file `my_accessibility_service.xml` and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:description="@string/service_desc"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"/>
```

Add permission to `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
```

Add your `AccessibilityService` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/my_accessibility_service"/>
</service>
```

You done!

Below is method to check status of `AccessibilityService`:

```
private static final int ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED = 1;

public static boolean isAccessibilitySettingsOn(Context context) {
    int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
    final String service = context.getPackageName() + "/" + MyAccessibilityService.class.getCanonicalName();
    try {
        accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(
                context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("AU", "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
    TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter mStringColonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');

    if (accessibilityEnabled == ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED) {
        String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(
                context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
        if (settingValue != null) {
            mStringColonSplitter.setString(settingValue);
            while (mStringColonSplitter.hasNext()) {
                String accessibilityService = mStringColonSplitter.next();

                if (accessibilityService.equalsIgnoreCase(service)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Note:** I have not tried but it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast Receiver is not supported in Oreo as manifest tag, you must have to register it as a Service/ Activity with context.registerReceiver(). Or you use the WorkManager to schedule something for specific network conditions.

use this code in `OnCreate`

```
    NetworkReciever  receiver = NetworkReciever ()
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

don't forget to unregister it in `onDestroy`

```
@Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  if (receiver != null) {
   unregisterReceiver(receiver);
   receiver = null;
  }
  super.onDestroy();
 }
```

and delete this from `Manifest`

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkReciever" >
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
       </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```