# How to register a network connectivity change receiver programmatically?

Tags: android, networking, android-broadcastreceiver

In my application I want to notify if a device has been lost network connection and if it's connected to a network again.

So I wrote a Broadcastreceiver like this:

```
class NetworkReceiver() : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    if (isNetworkConnected(context)) {
        //do some stuff
    } else {
        //do smoke stuff
    }
}

private fun isNetworkConnected(context: Context?): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager? = context?.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
            as ConnectivityManager?
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            val networkInfo: NetworkInfo? = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            if (networkInfo != null) {
                return networkInfo.isConnected
                        && networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
                        || networkInfo.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
            }
        } else {
            val network: Network? = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
            if (network != null) {
                val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
                return (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                        || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                        || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN))
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

My question how can I register this broadcast receiver in my activity to trigger the `NetworkReceiver` when my device is connected or disconnected from the network. Which `IntentFilter` should I use?

Comment: Possibly duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app

Comment: No because I want to register my broadcast receiver programmatically. The packages that where using in the answer are deprecated or don't exist anymore

Comment: Hey @dudi Did you find the proper solution for this??

Answer (score 1):

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;

import static com.keshav.networkchangereceiverexample.MainActivity.dialog;

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            if (isOnline(context)) {
                dialog(true);
                Log.e("keshav", "Online Connect Intenet ");
            } else {
                dialog(false);
                Log.e("keshav", "Conectivity Failure !!! ");
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            //should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
            return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In Manifest File :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<receiver android:name=".receivers.NetworkChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION is deprecated

Comment: This example works only for API Level 21+. Should I use the Broadcast Receiver for under API Level 21 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36447866/4776577 solution for Api Level 21+ ?

Comment: This should solve your issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26114247/4776577

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get it why this solved my issue? Can you explain me the details?

Comment: With this your application responds to changes made in network through Receiver and receives change in network through Service Manager. Mark answer as accepted if it helped in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In order to register your BroadcastReceiver programmatically, you can use the following code:

```java
private NetworkReceiver reciver;


@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        reciver = new NetworkReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        this.registerReceiver(reciver, filter);
    }


      @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.unregisterReceiver(reciver);

    }
```