# Why BroadcastReceiver don't work in React Native?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, react-native

I try to develop an application that in the future can run a service, the service I want to run when I connect to a network.

At the moment I only need the receiver to print in the log (using react-native log-android) that has been connected or disconnected, or to visualise a toast with a message, all this in the background not in the foreground.

Try the following,

First I put the receiver in the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>
  ...
  <receiver android:name="com.air_fighers_react_native.receiver.NetworkChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
</application>
```

**Even add the permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Create the receiver folder in java > com > air_fighters_react_native > receiver and inside the NetworkChangeReceiver.java file with the following code:

```
package com.air_fighters_react_native.receiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Cambio de conexion.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

With this it is supposed that it should be enough, however when running the application there are no problems, but when I close the application and activate and deactivate the WiFi the toast message is not displayed, not even when I have the application in the foreground.

I have already tried changing receiver to:

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver">
```

And changing NetworChangeReceiver to the same level as MainApplication and MainActivity in folders.

Comment: dup this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421930/connectivitymanager-connectivity-action-deprecated