# Realtime Network Check - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, network-programming, android-toast

I have an app and in that, I want to check the real-time network of the mobile phone.

This is my java code:

This is only some of the full java file.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);

    if (checkNetwork() == false) {
        Toast noNetwork = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sync is paused, due to no 
  internet...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        noNetwork.show();
    } else if (checkNetwork() == true) {
        Toast yesNetwork = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sync is turned on...", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        yesNetwork.show();
    }

    // This code we will add later - bottomNavigation.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.navigation_notes);
}

private boolean checkNetwork() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

If I open my app and navigate to this page, it shows the `internet is there` toast, but at the same time when I turn off mobile data, the other toast which shows `internet is not there` is not shown. I think the above code is not `real-time` or there is a problem with the toast, I don't know.

I want to know if there are ways in which I could make the above code real-time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can start a thread which call function after every second. I guess it's not a optimized way but a working way.

Answer (score 0):

Register a NetworkCallback using [registerNetworkCallback()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)) method. Example code is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36447866/14497159).