# NetworkInfo.Type is obsolete:"deprecated"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

For example i have this method:

```
public static bool IsConnectedMobile
        {
            get
            {
                var info = ConnectivityManagers.ActiveNetworkInfo;
                return info != null && info.IsConnected && info.Type == ConnectivityType.Mobile;
            }
        }
```

and i get an error here:  info.Type == ConnectivityType.Mobile;

[image]

And my question is, can i found an alternative? (without using other libraries)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo#getType()

Comment: info.GetType()  is not work because is of type System.Type, i think must be another solution

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use `getType` (since that is effectively what you are already using). Read the `This method was deprecated in API level 28.` bit.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveNetworkInfo` you need get it from `GetSystemService` Just use this code

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo;
if (activeNetwork != null)
{ 
   //connected to the internet
}
 else
{
  //not connected to the internet
}
```

& for more information go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547006/connectivitymanager-getnetworkinfoint-deprecated) thread

Answer (score 1):

This feature is platform-specific. Basically you can check the Network Connection status by using the below code:

```cs
var cm = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
bool isConnected = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo.IsConnected;
```

Should be quite straightforward.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

since API29 Android version 10.0, because NetworkInfo is deprecated

```
#if __ANDROID_29__
           // Code to execute on Android 10 (API level 29) or higher
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
            var activeNetwork = cm.ActiveNetwork;
            if (activeNetwork != null)
            {
                //connected to the internet
                Toast.MakeText(this, "connected to the internet", ToastLength.Long).Show();

                NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork);
                if (networkCapabilities != null && networkCapabilities.HasTransport(TransportType.Cellular))
                {
                    int networkSpeed = networkCapabilities.LinkDownstreamBandwidthKbps;

                    if (networkSpeed < 1000)
                    {
                        // Internet connection is slow
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Internet connection is slow", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //not connected to the internet
                Toast.MakeText(this, "not connected to the internet", ToastLength.Long).Show();
             
            }
#endif
```