# How to change my deprecated code in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-networking

I have a code to check if a user is connected

```
val connected:Boolean
        val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        connected = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN).state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED

if(connected){
   
} else {
}
```

but every time I build it tells me the its depreciated.

If there another way to check a user connectivity change please share.

Comment: [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547006/connectivitymanager-getnetworkinfoint-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

From the Android documentation:

> This method was deprecated in API level 23. This method does not support multiple connected networks of the same type. Use `getAllNetworks()` and `getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network)` instead.

In your case you probably actually want:

```
Network network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
NetworkCapabilities caps = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
connected = caps.hasCapability(TRANSPORT_VPN) && network.isConnected();
```

Comment: You can check the current android version with `if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) ...`

Comment: @Kayodel Please set your app to the latest SDK level to get use the latest API. 21 is indeed fine but you're restricted to the deprecated API in it.