# Exoplayer activity not playing video instead it's showing an empty screen

Tags: java, android, hlsl, exoplayer

I am newbie to the android studio, with the help of the developer guide I created this `exoplayer activity` but it's not playing video instead it's showing an empty screen. I created a `button` in my MainActivity, when I click that button it should open this player activity and play my hls streaming. Please help

**MY Player activity.java**

```
    package com.example.mystream;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;


public class playlive extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private PlayerView playerView;

    private Uri uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlive);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        try {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


    }

    private void play() {
        SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        uri = Uri.parse("http://localhost:1935/live/mystream/index.m3u8");
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, "app-name"));
// Create a HLS media source pointing to a playlist uri.
        HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource =
                new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);


        player.prepare(hlsMediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        play();
    }

    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        onBackPressed();
        player.release();
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        onBackPressed();
        player.release();
    }
}
```

**My playlive .xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".playlive">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/exo_buffering"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:resize_mode="fill"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Main activity**

```
package com.example.mystream;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        try {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent activity2Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), playlive.class);
                startActivity(activity2Intent);

            }
        });


    }



}
```

Comment: can't you see anything printed in logs? If there then please post here

Comment: @VirRajpurohit please check error message

Comment: Koteswara Raoha Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems in these two line

```
HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource =new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri); 
uri= Uri.parse("http://localhost:1935/live/mystream/index.m3u8");
```

You are trying to pass uri before initializing which is causing the issue.

try initializing before as below

```
uri= Uri.parse("http://localhost:1935/live/mystream/index.m3u8");
```

and then use it

```
HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource =new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: It's working but there is another problem with API 28 and API 29, my stream not playing in these 28,29 API's but working very fine for 24,25,26,27. Can you please help? I am updating error message.

Comment: @ChavaKoteswaraRao That is because of security policy updation. Try adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in application tag in manifest file.

Comment: OMG! it's worked like a champ. Thank you so much. you made my day and saved lots of time and pain.

Comment: Great! obliged as been able to help you. Happy Coding!

Comment: I need to check internet connectivity before launching exoplayer. I have updated my code, please look at once. My goal is, If there is no internet it should display "please connect the internet" and if internet is there It should play my exoplayer. Please help.

Comment: @ChavaKoteswaraRao I have added another answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the detailed desc of your requirement.

> Method to Check Net Connection

```
private boolean checkConnection(Context context) 
    {
        final ConnectivityManager mConnMngr= (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (mConnMngr!= null) {
            NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo = mConnMngr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (mNetworkInfo != null) {
                if ((mNetworkInfo .getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    return true;
                } else return mNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

> Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

> Usage

```
if (checkConnection(context)) {
   play(); 
} else {
   Toast.makeText(context,"No internet available!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Comment: NetworkInfo , getActiveNetworkInfo , getType , TYPE_WIFI, TYPE_MOBILE are deprecated. I am using min sdk 16 and targeted  sdk 29.

Comment: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53932141/6997819

Comment: When I clicking back button in this activity it's not going to previous activity instead it's closing. Can you help?

Comment: Check if you have written finish(); in intent code in previous activity. If so remove it. Also these are some basics of android. I suggest to take a deep dive in these things first.

Comment: Can you please have a look at mainactivity that I updated recently. As you suggested I will look at the basics. Thank you so much for your time. Fix this one issue.