# Is there any use case example where @RequiresApi is more useful than @TargetApi

Tags: android

to suppress API level warning, I usually prefer to use `@RequiresApi`, than `@TargetApi`.

As, `@RequresApi` seems newer and better than `@TargetApi`, according to [RequiresApi vs TargetApi android annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007365/requiresapi-vs-targetapi-android-annotations)

But, is there any real use case, where we can solve using `@RequiresApi`, but not using `@TargetApi`?

Answer (score 1):

`@RequiresApi` is more **clearly**, as described in its doc.

---

Moreover, `@RequiresApi` has FILED Target:

```
@Retention(CLASS)
@Target({TYPE,METHOD,CONSTRUCTOR,FIELD})
public @interface RequiresApi {
...
```

while `@TargetApi` not:

```
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface TargetApi {
...
```

So, `@RequiresApi` can be used like:

```
@RequiresApi(api = xxx)
private Foo bar;
```