# What is the use of @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M) before a method?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

What is the use of `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)` when it is in front of a method?

I need it to call `connectivityManager.activeNetwork`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RequiresApi vs TargetApi android annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007365/requiresapi-vs-targetapi-android-annotations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be simple.
For `connectivityManage.activeNetwork` minimum required OS for an android is M i.e: Marshmallow.
Your app support lower version that marshmallow but while using `connectivityManage.activeNetwork` it will be needing Marshmallow for lower version it doesn't work
if end user has Marshmallow or next versions this code will be executed.