# Connectivity Manager - AllNetworks Deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin

Can someone point me in the right direction when it comes to replacing this deprecated code for checking the internet connection on a device?

```
private val isNetworkAvailable = MutableStateFlow(false)

fun checkNetworkAvailability(context: Context): MutableStateFlow<Boolean> {

    val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(this)

    var isConnected = false
    // allNetworks Deprecated
    connectivityManager.allNetworks.forEach { network ->
        val networkCapability = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
        networkCapability?.let {
            if(it.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)) {
                isConnected = true
                return@forEach
            }
        }
    }

    isNetworkAvailable.value = isConnected

    return isNetworkAvailable
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can fetch the active network and check it's currently connected or not using [NetworkCapabilities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities)

```
private fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork // network is currently in a high power state for performing data transmission. 
            Log.d("Network", "active network $network")
            network ?: return false // return false if network is null
            val actNetwork = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network) ?: return false // return false if Network Capabilities is null
            return when {
                actNetwork.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> { // check if wifi is connected
                    Log.d("Network", "wifi connected")
                    true
                }
                actNetwork.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> { // check if mobile dats is connected
                    Log.d("Network", "cellular network connected")
                    true
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.d("Network", "internet not connected")
                    false
                }
            }
        }
        else{
          val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo

          return if (activeNetwork != null) {
            when (activeNetwork.type) {
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI -> true
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE -> true
                else -> false
            }
           }else {
            false
           }
         }
    }
```

**Note**: `connectivityManager.activeNetwork` requires permission `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`

Comment: What if the device is in Android 5 or Android 6? How do we check it there? At the moment, it will return false in this situation.

Comment: @IraklisEleftheriadis You need to use old deprecated method for android 6 or below.

Comment: Do you reckon that this code will work: @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            val connected = connectivityManager.allNetworks.any { network ->
                connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
                    ?.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                    ?: false
            }

            return if (connected) ConnectionState.Available else ConnectionState.Unavailable

Comment: I have edited the answer for else case also , Alternatively, You can look for the answers in here - [android-getallnetworkinfo-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242384/android-getallnetworkinfo-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative?answertab=trending#tab-top)